# Downloading akka-http jar files

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am unable to find akka-http jar files anywhere. Where can I download them from? ( without sbt )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven.

All versions - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-core_2.11

The latest stable 2.4.11 - 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-core_2.11/2.4.11

The direct link to 2.4.11 jar - 
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-http-core_2.11/2.4.11/akka-http-core_2.11-2.4.11.jar

If you want to browse all Akka artifacts - https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=akka.http